# Share image from an interactive drawing app to Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share, facebook-opengraph

I have a web app where one could draw mandala designs.

I want the user to be able to eventually share that image to Facebook.
I was able to convert the SVG element to base64, and to create a blob for the image, but then I don't know what's the best way to proceed.

It doesn't work if I pass it as an og:image meta tag when the user clicks the share button because the Facebook bot fetches the url as a new visitor, and therefore the image doesn't exist.

So what other solutions do I have?
[This is the app I mentioned](https://mariahajj.com/mandala-app/)

Comment: You share a URL to Facebook that when Facebook fetch that URL it gets the image.

Comment: You need to store the image on your server, and then create an HTML document that has its URL set in the `og:image` meta tag, so that the URL of this HTML document can then be shared on Facebook. (You could also share the image URL directly, but that will look less nice, and also anyone clicking on the image on Facebook, will be send to the plain image URL then.) You are going to need one HTML document (or to put that more precise, one individual URL - the actual HTML can of course be created dynamically by a script that gets a parameter passed) for each image you want to share.